How to run Python from root and child directory
In a Python repository with multiple standalone modules, I want to be able to run them individually in a child directory as well as connecting them from a run file in root.
Example repo tree:
/
├── SPS
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── SPS_run.py
│   └── components
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── comp1.py
│       └── comp2.py
├── Testing
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Test_run.py
│   └── components
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── comp3.py
│       └── comp4.py
└── main_run.py

The issue is importing local modules so that they can be run in main_run.py, Test_run.py, and SPS_run.py.
I set it up so that main_run.py, works with import relative to root.
From Test_run.py and SPS_run.py, I tried changing the directory like this without success:
# Get the directory of the script
current_script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Get the parent directory of the current script directory
parent_directory = os.path.dirname(current_script_directory)

# Change the current working directory to the parent directory
os.chdir(parent_directory)


you should install your packages. Your working directory shouldn't matter

Changing the system path in Test_run.py and SPS_run.py worked:
# Get the directory of the script
current_script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Get the root directory of the project
root_directory = os.path.dirname(current_script_directory)

# Add the root directory to sys.path
if root_directory not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(root_directory)

